# Unable to invoke the before_save callback for each user in console in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am following the Michael Haartl tutorial on Ruby on Rails. The user created before developing the signin function need to be assigned a remember token. For that, I use the following code in console:

```
User.all.each { |user| user.save(validate: false) }
```

Since I have:

```
before save :create remember token
```

in `app/models/user.rb`, this should create a remember token, but I get the following error on running this:

```
NameError: undefined local variable or method `base64' for     #<User:0x00559aefda7f20>
from /home/shivani/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activemodel-4.2.4/lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:433:in `method_missing'
from /home/shivani/myapp/app/models/user.rb:13:in `create_remember_token'
from /home/shivani/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:432:in `block in make_lambda'
from /home/shivani/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:164:in `call'
from /home/shivani/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:164:in `block in halting'
from /home/shivani/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:504:in `call'
from /home/shivani/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:504:in `block in call'
from /home/shivani/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:504:in `each'
from /home/shivani/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:504:in `call'
from /home/shivani/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:92:in `__run_callbacks__'
from /home/shivani/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:778:in `_run_save_callbacks'
from /home/shivani/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:302:in `create_or_update'
from /home/shivani/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:120:in `save'
from /home/shivani/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/validations.rb:37:in `save'
from /home/shivani/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/dirty.rb:21:in `save'
from /home/shivani/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:286:in `block (2 levels) in save'
... 14 levels...
from /home/shivani/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
from /home/shivani/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:68:in `console'
from /home/shivani/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
from /home/shivani/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/shivani/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
from /home/shivani/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
from /home/shivani/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
from /home/shivani/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
from /home/shivani/myapp/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/shivani/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
from /home/shivani/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `block in load'
from /home/shivani/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
from /home/shivani/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
from /home/shivani/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
from /home/shivani/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
```

Please help!
Contents of user.rb:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base 
    has_secure_password
    before_save { self.email = email.downcase }
    before_save :create_remember_token
    private
    def create_remember_token
       self.remember_token = SecureRandom.urlsafe Base64
    end
    validates :name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
    VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
    validates :email, presence: true, length: { maximum: 255 },
                format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX },
                uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }

    validates :password, presence: true, length: { minimum: 6 }
    end
```

Comment: Could you please share the contents of your `app/models/user.rb` file?

Comment: class User < ActiveRecord::Base
has_secure_password
before_save { self.email = email.downcase }
before_save :create_remember_token
private
def create_remember_token
self.remember_token = SecureRandom.urlsafe base64
endvalidates :name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
  validates :email, presence: true, length: { maximum: 255 },
                    format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX },
                    uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
  
  validates :password, presence: true, length: { minimum: 6 }

end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `app/models/user.rb`, change this:

```
def create_remember_token 
  self.remember_token = SecureRandom.urlsafe base64 
end
```

to this:

```
def create_remember_token 
  self.remember_token = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64 
end
```

You are missing an underscore (`_`) in `urlsafe_base54`

Source: http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.2/libdoc/securerandom/rdoc/SecureRandom.html#method-c-urlsafe_base64

Comment: Thank you so much!  It was a very rookie mistake

Comment: Glad it worked and welcome to sto! Please accept my answer if it works. :-)